# Prove the inequality: $|\arctan x-\arctan y|\le |x-y|;x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove the inequality: $|\arctan x-\arctan y|\le |x-y|;x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

What is the method for proving this inequality?

Comment: In general, the mean value theorem should be one of the first tools that comes to mind if you want to establish and inequality of the form "$|f(y) - f(x)| \leq C|y - x|$ for all $x$ and $y$ in some interval" for some differentiable function $f$, with $C$ a real number independent of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), along with the fact that $\arctan'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq 1$ for all $x$.